# MSBuild fails to build solution due to dependencies?

Tags: msbuild

I have an issue when building a VS2008 solution from command line.

When running the same .sln file from VS2008, it builds fine.

the problem is, some project that is a part of the solution, and is referenced by many other projects, seems to not be building BEFORE the other projects, making them fail since this shared project's output is not available at the time they build.

Is there a way to get around this ? (force checking dependencies?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using solution dependencies, switch to using project references instead.  Also, check to be sure the proper platform and configuration are specified for the dependencies.

Comment: not sure I understood your suggestion. I have a solution with ~ 30 projects. Some are relying on each other. When building this from Visual Studio, everything is fine. when invoking MSBuild to build this solution, it fails. I asked, why are there differences, and how to resolve them?

Comment: The problem appears that MSBuild is bulding the solution according to the ABC order of the project names, and doesn't construct the dependencies between the projects themselves.